# Mapping elements of two lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists (`a` and `b`). Some of the elements of `b` are also elements of `a`. I want to create a new list that maps each element of `a` to its "ultimate" element in `b` (so if some element `x` in `a` corresponds to `y` in `b`, but `y` also appears in `a` and that entry corresponds to `z` in `b`, I want to have `x` correspond to `z`). There can be more than one "ultimate" match, and if so I want to use a third list `c` to weigh the matches. Here's an example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
b = [6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 9, 3]
c = [.5, .3, 1, 1, 1, .5, .7]
```

The ideal output would be something like:

```
result = {1: [6, 9], 2: [6, 9, 7], 3: [7], 4: [6, 9], 5: [8]}
weights = {1: [.5, .5], 2: [.15, .15, .7], 3: [1], 4: [.5, .5], 5: [1]}
```

I tried to solve this with a `while` loop:

```
both = set(a).intersection(set(b))
mydict = dict(zip(a, b))
result = {x: mydict[v] if v in mydict.keys() else v for k, v in mydict.items()}

while set(result.values()).issubset(both)==False:
   result = {x: mydict[v] if v in mydict.keys() else v for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

but this doesn't handle situations in which more than one element matches or the weights. Any ideas how I can get at this? Thank you!

Comment: The posted code doesn't produce *anything* for `weights`.

Comment: You mean in my attempted solution? I got as far as the while loop I showed, but haven't figured out how to handle multiple matches and therefore how to come up with a weights output

Comment: Can you explain why in result under key `2` is the list `[6, 9, 7]`? Also why the weights `[.15, .15, .7]` for that key?

Comment: `2` maps to directly `1` and `3` in `b`. `1` maps to `6` and `9` and `3` maps to `7`. The weight on the combined elements of `1` equals 0.3, split by 0.5 and 0.5 each in `6` and `9` (by the corresponding entries for `1` in list `c`), so 0.3*0.5=0.15 in each. The weight on `7` is the same as the weight on `3`, i.e. .7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `networkx` to treat your lists as graph edges:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist(list(zip(a,b)),create_using=nx.DiGraph())

result = dict()
for x in a:
    result [x] = [n for n in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(n)==0 and n in nx.shortest_path(G,x)]

>>> d
{1: [6, 9], 2: [6, 7, 9], 3: [7], 4: [6, 9], 5: [8]}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Do you know if I can do something similar but using list `c` as weights, where I multiply the weights on each node as I go along to produce the example `weights` output?